# Remove class not working with reference to parent element

Tags: jquery, css

I want to remove class with reference to parent as below snippet. Why I am not able to do it

```js
$('div').click(function(){
    $('#parent div').removeClass('red');
    $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div class="red">A</div>
    <div class="red">B</div>
    <div class="red">C</div>
    <div class="red">D</div>
    <div class="red">E</div>
    <div class="red">F</div>
<div>
```

PS: I want modifying html to be the last option.

Comment: Want to remove `red` class from all div?

Comment: @Varun all divs withing that parent div.

Comment: @Community  what do you mean by `PS: I want modifying html to be the last option.

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to modify your selector for click event handler.

```js
$('#parent div').click(function(){
    $('#parent div').removeClass('red');
    $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div class="red">A</div>
    <div class="red">B</div>
    <div class="red">C</div>
    <div class="red">D</div>
    <div class="red">E</div>
    <div class="red">F</div>
<div>
```

or may want to stop the event from propagating.

```js
$('div').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#parent div').removeClass('red');
    $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div class="red">A</div>
    <div class="red">B</div>
    <div class="red">C</div>
    <div class="red">D</div>
    <div class="red">E</div>
    <div class="red">F</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Perfect answer as far as question is concerned (will accept it). I actually want to remove class on dom ready event not click. Any solution for that?

Comment: @Community -- You can remove the class using `$("#parent div").removeClass("red");` in `$(function() { ... })` wrapper. This will work as soon as DOM is ready.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you need to remove `red` class from all child.

```
$('#parent div').click(function(){
    $('#parent *').removeClass('red');
    $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the `.red` class to the currently clicked div and remove this very same class from it's siblings using `siblings()`.

```js
$('#parent div').click(function(){
    $(this)
      .addClass('red')
      .siblings()
      .removeClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div class="red">A</div>
    <div class="red">B</div>
    <div class="red">C</div>
    <div class="red">D</div>
    <div class="red">E</div>
    <div class="red">F</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have miss placed your selectors

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
  $('#parent div').click(function(){
        $('#parent div').removeClass('red');
        $(this).addClass('red');
    });

})
```

```css
  .red{color:red}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="parent">
        <div class="red">A</div>
        <div class="red">B</div>
        <div class="red">C</div>
        <div class="red">D</div>
        <div class="red">E</div>
        <div class="red">F</div>
    <div>
```